# How to obtain total number of reported crashes for an app via iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect, crash-reports

Does anyone know if it's possible to get a figure for the total number of reported crashes for an app via iTunes Connect?  Unless I'm missing something, it seems you can only get the percentage of crashes represented by a set of similar logs.

Or is there another way to get to this data?

Essentially I need to know whether a release has increased or decreased the number of crash reports received by iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really, no. Apple does... *something* with the crash reports. I think they're trying to be helpful and summarising the reports or filtering out reports that do not appear very often, but you won't see exact numbers in iTunes Connect and you won't see all the crashes.

The way I got around this -- though I was looking to improve the app rather than just collect metrics -- was to install a crash reporter in my app that sent the reports back to a server under my own control. (I wrote more about it [here](http://www.zx81.org.uk/computing/opinion/why-you-need-a-crash-reporter.html).)

Answer (score 0):

No, but there are two services I know of that provide this data, if you use their respective SDK:

http://www.crittercism.com/ - they have a free plan

http://www.mobclix.com/ - yes this is an ad platform, but they also have crash metrics